# setting up wampserver with dyndns

Tags: dyndns

I'm trying the free service of dyndns, so that I could just give the others the domain name that I created and not my ip address whenever I want them to see the webpage that I have done. 
I do not use any router in my home. And I'm accessing the domain address that I've created through dyndns perfectly, but when I tried giving the address to someone that is outside the home network. They cannot access it.
Do I need to setup something else on the os or the firewall so that they could access my site?
Cause I believe that whenever you install wampserver, it already adds rules to the windows firewall so that everybody could access it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check by disabling windows firewall.

check if your site works locally (http://localhost)
check from another computer via the dyndns name (http://dyndnshostname/)

open Port 80 on your home router pointing it to the computer with WAMP installed.